# How to mount subdirectory in Docker Volume Driver for Azure File Storage

Tags: docker, docker-volume, azure-files

Is there a way to mount to a subdirectory using the Azure Docker Volume Driver?
For example I have a share called docker but I want to add 3 subdirectories in this share to mount to different locations in the container.
For example I have certs, logs, config folders but I don't want to create a new share for each of these folders since config and certs only have 1 file each.

I would like to do something like: `docker run -i -t -v docker_volume/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v docker_volume/logs:/var/log/nginx -v docker_volume/certs:/etc/nginx/ssl... etc`